# Correct terminology for WiFi broadcasting and receiving devices?

Tags: wireless-networking, hotspot, terminology

I am using a mobile device's hotspot to broadcast a Wifi signal, and a computer that connects to the hotspot. What are the correct terms for these two devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the IEEE 802.11 standard, your mobile hotspot is acting as an *access point* (AP) and your computer that connects is a *station* (STA).